# ListActivity with multiple buttons per listitem

Tags: android, listactivity, items

I would like to create an ListActivity that's arranged somehow different than a usual list: it should contain, on each list row, multiple selectable items (image buttons to be more precise).

The items will be loaded from a SQLite db using a cursor.

My questions are:

1. I'm not sure I should use a ListActivity for this functionality. It looks like a List, but with custom design and behavior, so if anybody can suggest any other way to do it..
2. Assuming I can use a ListActivity, what I can't figure out is how can I do it. All the examples so far refer to list with only one item per row.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

> Create your custom adapter by
>   extending BaseAdapter class, So you
>   can custmize listview howerver you
>   want. Then palce your image buttons in
>   each listitem and provide
>   setOnClickListener for each image
>   buttons inside the adapter class:
>   Check out the following post for
>   coding help

: [Custom ListView](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/multicolumn-listview-with-image-icon/)

> Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, your example is still displaying an item on each row - even though it contains different types of data. Anyway, thank you - it still provides me with some ideas.

Comment: I could use some directions regarding the getItem() and getItemId() methods in the BaseAdapter. 1) I'm not sure what should I return from the getItem() method. 2) What's the id that I need to return from the getItemId() ? The index of one of the buttons in my row ? The index of the row among all the rows in the list ?

Comment: I can not access your link. I get a 403 error. Do you have another link?